# Ionic/Angular JS - ng-storage for checkbox item that is being pulled from a wordpress api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

In my application I have a checkbox list item, the data for the list items is from a api, I want to be able to user to click on the checkbox they want and that gets stored in localStorage, if I do it with the code below, it checks all the options but it does store it localy, but I want the user to be able to click on the checkbox they want and not have all the checkboxes checked. The code is:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in posts'>
<ul class="list">

<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags'>
 <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city">
 </label>
 <p ng-bind-html="tag.title"></p>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

APP.JS

```
  $localStorage.$default({
    option: {
      'city':true
    }
  });

  $scope.option = $localStorage;
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the below line

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city">
```

Every *checkbox* DOM element has the same `ng-model` value bound to it. 
You should assign a unique value to each checkbox. You can use `$index` prop of `ng-repeat`.

Example:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags track by $index'>
 <label class="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city[$index]">
 </label>
 <p ng-bind-html="tag.title"></p>
 </li>
```

Comment: One thing, i have a search filter on this item... as in the old code is: <li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags | filter: search'> but that does not work with the code above?